# If I incorporate Bing Maps in my PHP-MySQL driven website, do I need a license if I make the website live?

Tags: php, mysql, bing-maps

And another one would be do I really need to have a license? I mean Bing Maps is running just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an entreprise, I suppose the [Licensing Bing Maps for Enterprise](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing.aspx) page might interest you.

If you are not building an entreprise application... I don't find any documentation about that either...

Answer (score 0):

These [Terms of Use](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) might answer your question.